# How to set working directory for Node.js on windows?

Tags: windows, node.js

I just installed node.js for windows and it really was a breeze to get it running. I would like to use it as part of my build process to combine several files together like so:

```
// settings
var FILE_ENCODING = 'utf-8',
    EOL = '\n',
    DIST_FILE_PATH = 'dist/myAwesomeScript.js';

// setup
var _fs = require('fs');

function concat(fileList, distPath) {
    var out = fileList.map(function(filePath){
            return _fs.readFileSync(filePath, FILE_ENCODING);
        });
    _fs.writeFileSync(distPath, out.join(EOL), FILE_ENCODING);
    console.log(' '+ distPath +' built.');
}

concat([
    'foo/bar.js',
    'foo/lorem.js',
    'foo/maecennas.js'
], DIST_FILE_PATH);
```

This really works like a charm. However it does only work if I place all my scripts into the nodejs directory which is C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs and start the cmd process with admin rights.

But I need to have my project files in another directory ( say D:\git\projectx\ ) and would like to be able to run: node.exe D:\git\projectx\combine.js. Unfortunatly things doesn't work that way because node.exe will look for the files within it's own directory which is C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs. There must be away to start the nodejs process and tell it to use another directory as its working directory, am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

As someone pointed out on IRC. The solution to my problem was rather simple. Just `cd` into `D:\git\projectx` and then use `node.exe combine.js`. This makes it so that the current directory inside your script points to `D:\git\projectx`

However, I'm accepting Luke's answer since it seems to be also true ;-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set the current working directory using [process.chdir](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory), using Unix-style pathnames:

```
process.chdir('/temp/foo');
```

I'm not sure how to specify the drive prefix (`D:`) though.

Comment: Just add the drive to the directory string.
`process.chdir('c:/users');
process.cwd()`
result:
`'c:\\users'`

Comment: How and where to use it? Where exactly we should write this line? I wrote it on hit and trial base and could not succeed

Answer (score 9):

You can always use `__dirname` to represent the directory of the script you are in...

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
process.chdir('D:\\git\\projectx')
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's

```
process.chdir('D:\\\git\\projectx')
```

Comment: This is (almost) identical to the answer above it.

Comment: Well, actually it's `process.chdir('D:\\git\\projectx')` - 2 slashes after `D:`, not 3