# How to set the working directory for node.js in nodeclipse?

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I want to set a working directory for Node.js in Nodeclipse IDE.

Nodeclipe provides a run configuration to specify the Node path but not the working directory.

Is there any way to set this from Nodeclipse itself?

**Related :** [How to set working directory for Node.js on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956316/how-to-set-working-directory-for-node-js-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that the latest version(4.0) of Nodeclipse supports setting the working directory.

[image]

Comment: How to set the parameters on this screen