# fs.writeFile in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new to node js and want to save files with it

```
    fs.writeFile('myfile.txt', 'Content to write ', { flag: 'w' }, function(err) {
        if (err) 
            return console.error(err); 
            // read
        fs.readFile('myfile.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                return console.error(err);
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

It is working perfectly however i can not find **myfile.txt** in my Windows. Any solutions?

Comment: By default file will be created in the pwd (present working directory) or where the function is written.

Comment: `myfile.txt` should be in whatever directory is the current working directory when you launch your program from node.  If you're running it directly from the command line with `node myscript.js`, then it should be in the current working directory at the command prompt when you run it.  If you're running it from some IDE, then it will depend upon the IDE configuration.

Comment: If you want to control where it goes so it goes into your module's directory, then you can do this:  `const filename = path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.txt'); fs.writeFile(filename, ...)`.

Comment: Or, if you want to see where it will get put, you can do this: `console.log(path.resolve('myfile.txt'))`.

Comment: i am running it like browserify form.js > bundle.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set working directory for Node.js on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956316/how-to-set-working-directory-for-node-js-on-windows)

Comment: __dirname return "\"

Comment: @John it does not, my __dirname returns \ and it does not save there

Comment: Are you bundling your code?  `__dirname` will not be `/` in a vanilla nodejs program, but if you're bundling, the whole directory structure gets changed and `__dirname` is of no use.

Comment: yes i bundle the code and run it like :
**browserify form.js > bundle.js**

Comment: Well, you will will have to read about how directory access works in your bundled system.  It's completely different because your normal directory system has been collapsed and combined.  You will have to follow the rules in that system to understand how to put a file in a particular place or where it went when you have no path on it.  FYI, if you want a particular person to know that you've posted a comment, it's best to put @theirusername at the beginning of the comment so they get notified.  I only now stumbled on your last comment and got no notification because it wasn't tagged for me.

Comment: @jfriend00 my bad, but thanks a lot. I will do my best

Comment: If you're running this server-side or not in a browser, why are you bundling it anyway?

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed i am running it in a browser

Comment: @SamedMukush - Well, as far as I know there is NO access to the real `fs` module in a browser at all (there might be some simulations that don't write to disk).  That is functionality that a browser does not offer and no amount of webpacking will give you that functionality.  Next time, please be upfront in your question about what the target for the code is.  Saying that your packing it with browserify and running it in the browser would have IMMEDIATELY led the answers in a different direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr @jfriend00 . I just did not know it would make the case different. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: @SamedMukush - It makes all the difference in the world.  Browserify lets you run plain Javavscript in the browser or Javascript that uses browser APIs and it lets you use some nodejs library APIs that don't rely on native code or the underlying OS to implement.  But, things like the `fs` module or the `net` module which rely on native code access to underlying OS services cannot be used in code that runs in the browser because the browser does not support access to those kinds of services from Javascript running in the browser.  See my answer below for the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since you're using browserify and attempting to run this in a browser, there is NO access to the real `fs` module from code that runs in a browser at all. That is functionality that a browser does not offer and no amount of webpacking will give you that functionality.  So, you can't use the actual nodejs `fs` module in code that runs in the browser.

There are some packages that use different APIs to try to simulate portions of the `fs` module, but since you are not allowed to freely write anywhere you want to disk in a browser, the simulations are limited and not real file access.

Client-side browser code will typically store state into local storage, a cookie or indexedDB.  You can see the options described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage).

Comment: Thanks a lot, however i have less than 15 reputation and upvote it